# Expresión regular valida con otros caracteres de mas

Tags: php, regex

Tengo esta expresión que valida si existe "provincia" en una cadena pero al pasarle un string que tenga "provincial" lo reconoce y entra en la condición, lo que quiero es solo valide si existe únicamente "provincia" y nada mas, sin ningun tipo de caracter de mas

```
$hospital = "Hospital la provincial";
if(preg_match('/provincia/i', $hospital)){
     var_dump("true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que habrá mejores soluciones que esta pero intenta de esta manera. Tienes que utilizar el delimitador ‘**b**’

```
    $hospital = "Hospital la provincial";

    if(preg_match('/provincia\b/', $hospital)){

        var_dump("true");

    }
    else{
        echo "No es provincia";
    }
```

Comment: puedes mejorar tu  respuesta indicando que hace el deliminador `b` y si hay alguna documentacion relacionada que puedas agregar como punto de estudio o investigacion